# What is the best way to support several API versions when using Python Eve?

Tags: python, api, versioning, eve

I'm thinking of using Eve for the new project that I'm working on, but there's a requirement that there should be a way to introduce new API versions while still keeping the old ones. After reading the Eve documentation, I see that it doesn't really provide support for API versioning besides the ability to specify a version prefix in the config parameter.

What's the best way to implement the ability to support several API versions? The only way I can think of right now is to create a separate Eve app for each version and use application dispatching, but this seems overcomplicated to me...